# (Python) YouCompleteMe is ignoring my code and pip packages

Tags: python, vim, macvim, vim-plugin

I am using [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) on MacVim (vim 7.4 on OSX 10.9.4) for Python code auto-completion.

YCM works perfectly when referencing Python built-in functionality (like `os.*` stuff), but it doesn't seem to be able to auto-complete identifiers written by me or from various packages installed using pip.

According to its documentation, YouCompleteMe uses Jedi for Python code completion, and [the Jedi GitHub page](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi) clearly states that Jedi can auto-complete any code, not just standard library identifiers.

Does anyone have any idea regarding why Jedi isn't picking up any packages or custom code?

Comment: You may not have include your project path. Or, I t might not have identified your files.