# YouCompleteme only works for stdlib modules

Tags: python, vim, youcompleteme

I have a problem relating to YouCompleteMe and Python. When I try to autocomplete standard library packages like `os.*` everything works. When I try the same with pip installed packages like flask it does not.

I found the same question but no answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28339946/python-youcompleteme-is-ignoring-my-code-and-pip-packages)

vim --version prints:

> VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jun  9 2016 09:35:16)
>       Included patches: 1-1910
>       Compiled by Arch Linux
>       Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
>       +acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary
>       +arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
>       +autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
>       -balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     +tcl/dyn
>       -browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     +termguicolors
>       ++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
>       +byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
>       +channel         +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
>       +cindent         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +timers
>       -clientserver    +iconv           +packages        +title
>       -clipboard       +insert_expand   +path_extra      -toolbar
>       +cmdline_compl   +job             +perl/dyn        +user_commands
>       +cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
>       +cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
>       +comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
>       +conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
>       +cryptv          +linebreak       +python/dyn      +viminfo
>       +cscope          +lispindent      +python3/dyn     +vreplace
>       +cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
>       +cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
>       +dialog_con      +lua/dyn         +rightleft       +windows
>       +diff            +menu            +ruby/dyn        +writebackup
>       +digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -X11
>       -dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
>       -ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xim
>       +emacs_tags      -mouseshape      +startuptime     -xsmp
>       +eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      -xterm_clipboard
>       +ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xterm_save
>       +extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax          -xpm
>          system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
>            user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
>        2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
>             user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
>         fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
>       Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
>       Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE  -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -lncurses -lelf -lnsl    -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl   -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE -lperl -lpthread -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lc   -L/usr/lib -ltclstub8.6 -ldl -lz -lpthread -lieee -lm

Comment: You might  have to include your file path in set path command.

Comment: I reinstalled the AUR package, now everything works fine, thx!

Answer (score 1):

add 
let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf = '~/.vim/.ycm_extra_conf.py' 
to your .vimrc

copy .ycm_extra_conf.py from https://github.com/Valloric/ycmd/blob/master/cpp/ycm/.ycm_extra_conf.py
and move it to ~/.vim/